Can you recommend essential Islamic books for deepening my understanding and clearing my doubts?
Assalamu Alaikum everyone,
I'm a born Muslim with a strong interest in Islam but haven't studied it deeply. Watching khutbas and reading online often leaves me confused, especially about hadith authenticity and conflicting opinions. I've read some surahs and Tafsir Ibn Kathir, but I want to learn more comprehensively. Can you recommend essential books by trusted scholars on:

Basics and pillars of Islam, including the four madhabs and verifying hadith authenticity.
The life of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him).
Living according to Allah's guidance and the Prophet’s example.

JazakAllah Khair for your help!
Wa Alaikum Assalam.

go to al-islam.org
